# what dose "Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules" mean?

Tags: objective-c, swift, module, clang

I saw the meaning of "Allow Non-modular Includes In Framework Modules" in Xcode.

> Enabling this setting allows non-modular includes to be used from within framework modules. This is inherently unsafe, as such headers might cause duplicate definitions when used by any client that imports both the framework and the non-modular includes.

but it's so abstract，anyone can give me some more detail and example, and tell me what happened behind this?

another question is that this error only happened in dynamic/static framework structure, not in static library, why?